# How to return assets or any variable using @returns annotation

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Im trying to return query results from transaction.Here is my code.

```
/**
* Sample transaction
* @param {org.zcon.healthcare.SearchPatient} tx
* @returns{org.zcon.healthcare.Patient[]}
* @transaction
*/
async function SearchPatient(tx){
let queryString = `SELECT org.zcon.healthcare.Patient WHERE (`;
let conditions = [];
if (tx.hasOwnProperty('firstName')) {
    var firstName =tx.firstName;
    conditions.push(`(firstName == "${firstName}")`)
};
if (tx.hasOwnProperty('lastName')) {
    var lastName = tx.lastName;
    conditions.push(`(lastName == "${lastName}")`)
};
if (tx.hasOwnProperty('gender')) {
    var gender = tx.gender;
    conditions.push(`(gender == "${gender}")`)
};
if (tx.hasOwnProperty('birthDate')) {
    var dob =tx.birthDate;
    conditions.push(`(birthDate == "${dob}")`)
};
if (tx.hasOwnProperty('ssn')) {
    var ssn=tx.ssn;
    conditions.push(`(ssn == "${ssn}")`)
};
if (tx.hasOwnProperty('medicalRecordNumber')) {
    var mrn = tx.medicalRecordNumber;
    conditions.push(`(medicalRecordNumber == "${mrn}")`)
};
queryString += conditions.join(' AND ') + ')';
console.log(queryString);
let finalQuery =  buildQuery(queryString);
console.log(finalQuery);
const searchPatient = await query(finalQuery);
if(searchPatient.length ==0){
    throw "No Patient Records found!!"
}else
  return searchPatient;   
}
```

But it's not returning the array except transaction details. Do I need to change the return type? Or I'm missing anything else?

Comment: you need to define the return type in .cto  file also.                                                                                  @returns(Patient[])                                                                                      transaction SearchPatient {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its a query transaction, as Mohammed indicates ; you need to define the return type. Also define the commit type - as in

```
@commit(false) 
@returns(Patient[]) 

transaction SearchPatient { 
<txn definition here> 
}
```

in your model (.cto) file.

Its all documented (with examples) here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts

Comment: Can we test this in playground bluemix? I did the above changes. But still I'm not able to get the array in return. I'm trying this in bluemix in the browser.

Comment: you return it to a client - read the docs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#read-only-transaction-processor-functions-query-processor-functions . Playground is not intended as a client to test - but can return you the array results (as I've posted in your other post) but the results are returned out of the TP to the calling client. There is sample code in the docs